# Getting a specific node's value without it being json parsed using Jackson

Tags: java, jackson

I have a Json data which I am converting into POJO using Jackson which works perfectly fine. However, now I have a specific requirement to get value for a specific node, as is, without it being Json decoded. It holds some dynamic keys which I can not put as specific properties of my POJO, rather I need its value as is, which I can decode later.

Please help me get it right.

Here is an example json:

```
{"node":{
        "status":{"code":200,"message":"OK"},
        "fields":{"main_id":{"value":1372669257},
        "from_node":{"value":"{\"1\":\"\",\"0\":\"Categorized\",\"557\":\"K1\",\"55446\":\"K2\",\"5552\":\"K3\",\"57\":\"L9\"}"},
        "previous_id":{"value":1372669640},
        "new_counter":{"value":8}
        }
    }
}
```

From this JSON data, I am mapping all the keys like code, message, fields etc into my POJO. Now in that POJO class I want a new property called "value", where I want the value from the "from_node" to be mapped as string.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "as is", as to me that sounds like Kantian Metaphysics. Lovely, but not SO!

Comment: mmm serialize it using the java object and the jackson `ObjectMapper` to have the string...

Comment: Are you trying to get the JSON data as a string fragment in your POJO? Or just store an associative map of key-value pairs?

Comment: @Perception Yes, I am trying to get a particular node of the JSON data as a string fragment in my POJO.